# Excel VBA Dropdown list, default value

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, default-value, vba

Using following code to create dropdown if A Col has a value.
How do I set **No** as default value?

```
  Dim myList As String, r As Range

  myList = "Yes,No"

  If w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1" Then
    For Each r In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
            With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
            End With
            If r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then r.Offset(, 2).Value = "No"
            If r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then Split myList, ","
            End If
      Next r
  End If
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but how about just .Value = “No” :)

Comment: Where should I set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the default when you apply the *DV*:

replace:

```
With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
End With
```

with:

```
With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
End With
r.Offset(, 2).Value = "No"
```

Comment: It places "No" but it overwrites the value if it already is set to "Yes" on another row.

Comment: This seems to fix it `If r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then r.Offset(, 2).Value = "No"`. I update my question with the solution.

Comment: @MarkusSacramento YES. You are correct.  My reading of the question is to set the value of the cell to a default value, regardless of what its current contents is......... *(I may have mis-understood the question)*

Comment: @MarkusSacramento  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A Validation drop-down does not have a default. You can fill empty cells with "No" and use "No,Yes" for your list.

Excel, unlike a database, doesn't require (by default) initiating a new record/row, so a default does not make sense to Excel. Given this, just filling all blank cells with "No" is not helpful, because you wouldn't know whether the user knows, or intended, to select "No".

(With a database the user will physically see the field value assuming the default "No" value, and they then have the clear choice to accept it or change it.)

Comment: Okay, how to fill those blank cells with "No" inside a dropdown list code?